# Controller not inheriting methods from ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, inheritance

I have a Rails 6 API-only project that is acting weird.

My application controller has a method to rescue common exceptions:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :rescue_errors

  private

  def rescue_errors
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
      render json: { error: { message: ['Record not found'] } }, status: :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

This is my UsersController:

```
class Api::V1::User::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    render json: { user_id: user.id }, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Then I try to access an User id that doesn't exist to get rescued RecordNotFound exception, that inherits from ApplicationController, and I get this error:

```
<NoMethodError: undefined method `rescue_errors' for #<Api::V1::User::UsersController:0x00007f71484b3be0>\nDid you mean?  rescue_handlers>
```

Why UserController isn't inheriting rescue_errors from ApplicationController?

Comment: Is your Rails app API only or both API and standard MVC ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder API only

Comment: Did you [read the comments](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb#L51) preceding how `rescue_from` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this won't work because of how `rescue_from` [is implemented](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods) in Rails.  It should be used inside the class definition and not wrapped inside a private method.

So you should just do:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :rescue_errors

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
    render json: { error: { message: ['Record not found'] } }, status: :not_found
  end    
end
```

Comment: I tried this before, but errors simply doesn't get rescued and are thrown as exceptions:
<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=12>

Comment: When I put the "rescue_from..." directly on ApplicationController class, without defining it inside a method, it works perfectly.
But when I put it on a concern or inside a method it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found_response

  private

  def not_found_response(exception)
    render json: { code: 404, status: 'Not Found', error: exception.message }, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

You can create different answers for each of the possible errors.